# Stop CruiseControl.NET auto build

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I have CruiseControl.NET setup with SVN source control.

I have all my projects working perfectly, builing and deploying to my different staging environments.

However, CC.NET automatically starts building whenever a commit is made to the project in SVN. We want to build on demand, not automatically all the time, because all our builds deploy to staging and out testers will be logged out all the time.

Anyone who knows how to disable this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was pretty simple, though I should learn to read the documentation on the Triggers section of a Project in CC.NET:

> Specifying an empty element (`<triggers />`) means integrations are only ever forced manually (for example using CCTray or the Web Dashboard.) Not including a  element at all means the project has a single Interval Trigger with default configuration.

Comment: The behavior of not including a <triggers> element has changed from 1.4.3 onwards. It now behaves the same way as an empty element (<triggers />), meaning integrations are only ever forced manually:

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Trigger+Blocks

Answer (score 0):

If you access the admin site of the CCnet, you can stop the auto build and use the force option to force the build, or you can set a time for checking for new commits high enough, maybe 8 hours, to have 1 build each day before the testers start working.

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

version : 1.4.0.3524
 - works as designed
it's no way to see in web dashboard, but tray client clearly says: "Project is not automatically triggered"